# How to rank by referring to date and status in sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sql-order-by, window-functions

```
customer product  status     surrender_date 
-------------------------------------------
A          a      invalid      2020/8/1
A          b      invalid      2020/9/1
A          c      valid        null
B          a      invalid      2020/7/1 
B          b      valid        null
B          c      valid        null
```

First, I'd like to group by customer:

```
customer product  status     surrender_date 
-------------------------------------------
A          a      invalid      2020/8/1
A          b      invalid      2020/9/1
A          c      valid        null
```

Second,`rank`will be added by referring to its `surrender_date` and `status`, the newer the date is, the rank is higher.

On the other hand, if `status = valid`, rank will always be `1`.

```
customer product  status     surrender_date  rank
--------------------------------------------------
A          a      invalid      2020/8/1       3
A          b      invalid      2020/9/1       2
A          c      valid        null           1
```

Therefore my desired result is the following:

```
customer product  status     surrender_date  rank
--------------------------------------------------
A          a      invalid      2020/8/1       3
A          b      invalid      2020/9/1       2
A          c      valid        null           1
B          a      invalid      2020/7/1       3
B          b      valid        null           1
B          c      valid        null           1
```

My attempt cannot include`valid` status..

```
select
    t.*,
    rank() over(partition by customer order by surrender_date desc) rank
from 
    mytable
```

If someone has an opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your example. Is rank = 2 *higher* than rank = 3? Usually 2 is considered "lower" than 3 (even when referring to ranks). Or did you make a mistake in your example? 2020/9/1 is newer than 2020/8/1, so it should get the "higher" rank; in your example it gets rank 2, while the older row gets rank 3. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding another criteria to the `order by` clause of the window function, which puts "valid" status first:

```
select
    t.*,
    rank() over(
        partition by customer 
        order by case when status = 'valid' then 0 else 1 end, surrender_date desc
    ) rn
from mytable
```